# Как правильно создать хитбокс для линии в Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, графика

Я пишу простой редактор линий на Qt. Столкнулся с проблемой выделения конкретного объекта мышкой. Переопределив `shape()` я начал строить вокруг линии хитбокс в виде набора прямоугольников, но проблема в том что иногда эти прямоугольники получаются разной толщины или образуют разрывы. Есть ли какой-то метод создать хит бокс иначе. Линия представлена в виде набора точек и толщины. Также присутствует параметр `sens` который указывает дополнительный припуск для хитбокса.
[image: Пример получаемого хитбокса обозначен зелёным]

```
 QVector<QPoint> MyItem::CrtSegment(QPointF p0, QPointF p1)
                    {
                        float p0_x = p0.x(), p0_y = p0.y(), p1_x = p1.x(), p1_y = p1.y();
                        QRectF r_p0, r_p1;
                        r_p0 = QRectF(QPoint(p0_x + sens, p0_y - pen_width - sens), QPoint(p0_x - sens, p0_y + pen_width + sens));
                        r_p1 = QRectF(QPoint(p1_x + sens, p1_y - pen_width - sens), QPoint(p1_x - sens, p1_y + pen_width + sens));
                        QVector<QPoint> v;
                        if (p0_x <= p1_x)
                        {
                            if (p0_y <= p1_y)
                                v = { r_p0.topLeft().toPoint(),r_p1.topLeft().toPoint(),r_p1.bottomRight().toPoint(),r_p0.bottomRight().toPoint(),r_p0.topLeft().toPoint() };
                            if (p0_y > p1_y)
                                v = { r_p0.bottomLeft().toPoint(),r_p1.bottomLeft().toPoint(),r_p1.topRight().toPoint(),r_p0.topRight().toPoint(),r_p0.bottomLeft().toPoint() };
                        }
                        if (p0_x >= p1_x)
                        {
                            if (p0_y <= p1_y)
                                v = { r_p0.bottomLeft().toPoint(),r_p1.bottomLeft().toPoint(),r_p1.topRight().toPoint(),r_p0.topRight().toPoint(),r_p0.bottomLeft().toPoint() };
                            if (p0_y > p1_y)
                                v = { r_p0.topLeft().toPoint(),r_p1.topLeft().toPoint(),r_p1.bottomRight().toPoint(),r_p0.bottomRight().toPoint(),r_p0.topLeft().toPoint() };
                        }
                        return v;
                    }

        QPainterPath MyItem::shape() const
                {
                    QPainterPath path;
                        if(!points.isEmpty())
                        {
                            for(auto i = 1;i<points.size();i++)
                            {
                                path.addPolygon(QPolygon(CrtSegment(points\[i - 1\], points\[i\])));
                            }
                        }
                    return path;
                }
```

Comment: а вы не забыли про `boundingBox`?

Comment: По-моему это все ни к чему. Определяйте близость интересующей точки к другим точкам / отрезкам.